# Use event inside ngOnInit in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using a method inside `ngOninit` which stops the propagation.

Here when, I run the `ng lint`, it is showing the event as deprecated. How can I resolve it?

```
ngOnInit() {    
    this.MyMethod(event);    
}

MyMethod($event: Event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Update:

```
ngOnInit() {    
        const even = window.event;
        this.clickedInside(even);    
    }

    MyMethod($event: Event) {
        $event.preventDefault();
        $event.stopPropagation();
    }
```

I want just the window.event in my ng oninit but when I am running the build, it is showing as depecrated. How to properly pass the current event in the ngOninit method.

Comment: What exactly you're trying to do? This lacks context. Help community to help you.

Comment: What event exactly are you passing as an argument to `MyMethod`?